# css style to bootstrap .dropdown-menu class not working with ancestor/descendant selector

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

My webpage includes some code via php include.
This included code contains several buttons that open dropdown menus.
I'm using bootstrap, so styling for class .dropdown-menu from bootstrap's css apply by default to these dropdown menus.

I'd like to change the width of a particular dropdown menu (resize to 100px).

```
<!-- Sizes dropdown -->
<div class="btn-group women" id="women_sizes">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-pale dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
    size 
    <!-- <span class="caret"></span> --> 
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      ...
  </ul>
</div><!-- end #women_sizes -->
```

I've tried the following css code, and I don't know why it doesn't work.  I've tried putting this code in a  tag in the page's header and in a linked external css file, which I include after bootstrap's css.

```
#women-sizes .dropdown-menu  {
  min-width:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: seems to be working here? http://jsbin.com/xeqovahegu/2/edit?html,output

Comment: thanks for putting that up.  however it's not working for me.  It just sizes at 160px regardless.  I cloned and tried a few different widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using an underscore `women_sizes` as a separator in the HTML...

```
<div class="btn-group women" id="women_sizes">
```

Here you are using a dash `#women-sizes` in the CSS.

```
#women-sizes .dropdown-menu {
```

Pick one method and stick with it. Bootstrap uses dashes, so I would go with that.